# Correct way to save list of lists into string with multiple lines?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists and I want to print it into multiple lines. But I have to save it into a variable first which means I can't just print each element of the outer list.

```
def __str__(self):
    string = ""
    length = len(self.lst)
    for index in range(length):
        string += str(self.lst[index])
        if (index != length-1):
            string += "\n"
    return string
```

This doesn't seem the best approach but it works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you trying to save to a file in the `__str__` function? The purpose of that function is to make a string representation of a class. You probably should create your own function which uses `open('filename.txt', 'w')` which opens a file that you can use to write data to. [This](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) can probably help. You don't need to save the data to a variable if you just use the list of lists as the structure to loop through to write to a file.

Comment: That was my bad. I meant multiple lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
class LOL:
    """ List of lists. """
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.lst = data

    def __str__(self):
        return ('[\n' +
                '\n'.join('  ' + repr(sublist) for sublist in self.lst) +
                '\n]')


lol = LOL([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], [1, 2, 42]])
print(lol)
```

Output:

```
[
  ['a', 'b', 'c']
  ['d', 'e']
  [1, 2, 42]
]
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using this: `return '\n'.join(repr(sublist) for sublist in self.lst)`

Answer (score 0):

You might get what you want with something like `join()`.  For example:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(', '.join(map(str, range(5))) for _ in range(3)))
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: It should keep the [] at the beginning and end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit shorter and more Pythonic and if you don't have a problem with new line in the end:

```
def __str__(self):
    string = ""
    for a_list in self.lst:
        string += str(a_list) + "\n"
    return string
```

Comment: I was doing that but the last line can't end with \n

Answer (score 0):

The entire function body of your `__str__` can be replaced by a single line of code as follows:

```
def to_string(self):
    return '\n'.join(str(a) for a in self.lst)
```

I have renamed this function since you shouldn't use `__str__` the way your are doing, as Karl pointed out.  In general `__str__` should return a short string that you wouldn't mind looking at on the console.

You may find that you only call `to_string` in one place.  Once you realize that the function can be replaced by a single line, you may want to inline the entire expression instead of making a function call.  It's idiomatic Python and therefore easy to read for someone with some experience.

Comment: Why should I not use `__str__`? Karl thought I wanted to use `__str__` to print to a file (typo of mine, wrote file instead of line). I know there is also `__repr__` which is meant for what you said. Isn't `__str__` equivalent to Java's toString()?

Comment: The description of `__str__` from the Python language reference docs: `Called by str(object) and the built-in functions format() and print() to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of an object.`  Writing a `__str__` implementation that returns a long string containing multiple \n is most definitely not good style.

Answer (score 0):

This works OK:

```
# We supose all elements are strings, otherwise you must apply data transformation
my_list = [['a','b','v'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i'], ['j','k','l']]

# Items separator: comma
sep = ','

# Converting each sublist in string
processed_sublists = [sep.join(item) for item in my_list]

# Lists (lines) separator: \n
sep = '\n'

result = sep.join(processed_sublists)

print(result)
```

Result:

> > a,b,v
> >
> > d,e,f
> >
> > g,h,i
> >
> > j,k,l